# Supporting various Image formats and strong them in sqlite

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, sqlite

Am trying out a simple iPhone App wherein one can choose a picture from the existing photos in their iPhone PhotoLibrary. Am storing the chosen images into a SQLite DB like this:

```
        NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);        
        sqlite3_bind_blob(statement, 1, 
                          [imageData bytes], [imageData length], NULL);
```

The above does it only for PNG. And in UIKit API there is only similar conversion (from UIImage to NSData) for JPG. How do I do this for images of other formats (like bmp,tiff,gif,etc)?

In UIImage class, it says it supports a variety of formats, but the conversion methods are provided only for png & jpg ( UIImagePNGRepresentation and UIImageJPEGRepresentation).

[image]

Comment: any help on this please? any pointers atleast?

Answer (score 0):

You have two things separate going on here, reading various image formats and saving the image. `UIImage` can read any of those formats listed. So open a .bmp or a .tiff and you'll be fine.

When it comes to saving that data out again, you have two built-in options, `UIImagePNGRepresentation` and `UIImageJPEGRepresentation`, which each take a `UIImage` and convert it into either a PNG or JPEG representation of the image. The `NSData` that you get from either of these two functions can be written to a database (or more commonly to a file as we were discussing on your other question), and then read back in later. If you wanted to save the file back as a BMP, TIFF or other, you'd need to find libraries that do that.

So it doesn't matter what you start with, you can still save it as a PNG (lossless) or JPEG (lossy) file within your app. Naturally, if you open a BMP and save it as a PNG, there will be a minor loss of quality because you're creating a new generation of the image, but it would in almost all cases be unnoticeable.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

To generate images in formats other than PNG and JPEG, you use CGImageDestination.